# Definition of BDF sum of extensions

Tags: c-star-algebras

The sum of two extension is defined in the following way:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be two separable C*-algebras with $\mathcal{B}$ stable and $\phi,\psi: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{M(B)/B}$ be two extensions of $\mathcal{B}$ by $\mathcal{A}$. Then the sum of extension is defined in the following way:
>   $$(\phi \oplus \psi)(a)=\pi(S)\phi(a)\pi(S^*)+\pi(T)\psi(a)\pi(T^*)$$
>   where $S,T \in \mathcal{M(B)}$ are isometries such that $SS^*+TT^*=1_{\mathcal{M(B)}}$.

I do not follow the motivation why we define the sum in this way and what is the guarantee that we find two such isometries $S$ and $T$ such that $SS^*+TT^*=1_{\mathcal{M(B)}}$.

Can you refer me some notes or papers where I can find the details of this BDF sum?

Also I do not get the idea why we define the BDF equivalance of extensions as follows:

> Two extensions $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent if there exists $\rho,\sigma: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{M(B)/B}$ trivial extensions such that 
>   $$\phi \oplus \rho \sim_u \psi \oplus \sigma$$

Any reference of notes and paper will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By extension, you mean the corresponding Busby invariant?

Comment: How are you thinking of $\mathcal{M}(B)$?

In "Elements of KK-theory" by Jensen and Thomsen, the multiplier algebra is thought of as the space of adjointable operators on $B$ as a right Hilbert $B$-module. In the first couple of sections, it is shown that $\mathcal{L}_B(\mathcal{H}_B) \simeq \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{K} \otimes B)$, which is in turn isomorphic to $\mathcal{M}(B)$ by stability. $\mathcal{H}_B$ is a lot like a countable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, so proceed how you would in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ to get two isometries $S,T$ such that $SS^* + TT^* = 1$.

Comment: For $\mathcal{M(B)}$, I am more used to the definition of Idealizer. Let $\phi: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow B(\mathcal{H})$ be a non-degenerate representation. Then idealizer of $\mathcal{B}$ =$\{T \in B(\mathcal{H})| T\mathcal{\phi(B)} \subseteq \mathcal{B} \text{ and } \mathcal{\phi(B)}T \subseteq \mathcal{\phi(B)}\}$. we can show $\mathcal{\phi(B)}$ sits inside Idealizer of $\mathcal{B}$ as an essential ideal and Idealizer satisfies the universal property of multiplier algebra. Can you write the idea in the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can obtain the two isometries:

For any $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$, $M(A)\otimes M(B)$ always embeds unitally in $M(A\otimes B)$ (tensor products here are minimal).  Thus if $B$ is stable, $M(B)\otimes\mathbb B$ embeds in $M(B\otimes\mathbb K)\cong M(B)$.  So take two isometries $s,t\in\mathbb B$ such that $ss^*+tt^*=1_\mathbb B$, and put $S=1_{M(B)}\otimes s$, $T=1_{M(B)}\otimes t$.

For motivation, I would recommend consulting the original papers of Brown, Douglas, and Fillmore.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I also don't get how this condition on summing both isometries to 1 is necessary.

Comment: @craaaft The condition $ss^*+tt^*=1_{\mathbb{B}}$ implies that $SS^*+TT^*=1_{\mathcal{M(B)}}$.  Intuitively, this means that $s$ and $t$ cut the Hilbert space into orthogonal subspaces, whose direct sum is the whole space, and such that each subspace is isomorphic to the whole space.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of that. I have a more fundamental question - why can't we define the sum as just $(\phi \oplus \psi)(a)=\phi(a)+\psi(a)$?

Comment: @craaaft  The map you've defined isn't a $*$-homomorphism

Comment: Ok I tried to check if it is a $*$-homomorphism and I end up with this:
$\pi(S)\phi(ab)\pi(S)^{*} + \pi(T)\psi(ab)\pi(T)^{*} =
\pi(S)\phi(a)\pi(S)^{*}\pi(S)\phi(b)\pi(S)^{*} +
\pi(T)\psi(a)\pi(T)^{*}\pi(S)\phi(b)\pi(S)^{*} +
\pi(S)\phi(a)\pi(S)^{*}\pi(T)\psi(b)\pi(T)^{*} +
\pi(T)\psi(a)\pi(T)^{*}\pi(T)\psi(b)\pi(T)^{*}$
which would mean that $T^{*}S=0$ and $S^{*}T=0$ for the equality to be correct. Is that right? Also is there a more general lemma about how those isometries give rise to a $*$-homomorphism in general? Thank you!

Comment: @craaaft I'll answer your first question here, and suggest you make a new post on this website regarding the second.  We have $T^*S=0$ by the $C^*$-identity:
\begin{align*}
\|T^*S\|^2
=\|S^*TT^*S\|
=\|S^*(1-SS^*)S\|
=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: ah I see. thank you, will do!

Comment: @craaaft You're welcome, glad to help!

Comment: Sorry, another question that I have is I am wondering why for example in the original paper (and other places) they don't talk at all how the BDF sum comes to be but just define it as a direct sum. Is saying that something is a direct sum imply that the sum looks in that specific way?